# Rails association has_one, through, dependent destroy does not destroy related objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, ruby-on-rails-5, dependent-destroy

I can't find documentation in the Rails site that covers this particular use case. Presumably normal `has_one` will work (because it says so). I've not tried yet.

Given two models and a join table for the association, I would expect `dependent: :destroy` to cause the join table row to be deleted on destroying the parent model.

The chained deletion only works for a has_many relationship (this code not shown here, but it's easy to modify the models to achieve it).

I believe there would be a workaround based on using has_many with uniqueness constraints (possibly on the join table). But I don't think I should have to!

> IRB to reproduce:
>
> ```
> 000 > a = ModelA.create(name: "Fruity")
>
> ( output )
>
> 001 > b = ModelB.create(interesting_thing: "Tennis")
> ( output )
>
> 002 > a.model_b = b
> ( output )
>
> 003 > pp ModelAModelB.all
>
>   ModelAModelB Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "model_a_model_bs".* FROM "model_a_model_bs"
> [#<ModelAModelB:0x005609f4fa5128
>   id: 1,
>   model_a_id: 1,
>   model_b_id: 1,
>   created_at: Fri, 27 Jan 2017 13:37:15 UTC +00:00,
>   updated_at: Fri, 27 Jan 2017 13:37:15 UTC +00:00>]
>
> 004 > a.destroy
>
>    (0.1ms)  begin transaction
>   SQL (3.0ms)  DELETE FROM "model_as" WHERE "model_as"."id" = ?  [["id", 1]]
>    (4.5ms)  commit transaction
> ```
>
> Models:
>
> ```
> class ModelA < ApplicationRecord
>   has_one :model_a_model_b
>   has_one :model_b, through: :model_a_model_b, dependent: :destroy
> end
>
> class ModelB < ApplicationRecord
>   has_one :model_a_model_b
>   has_one :model_a, through: :model_a_model_b, dependent: :destroy
> end
>
>
> class ModelAModelB < ApplicationRecord
>   belongs_to :model_a
>   belongs_to :model_b
> end
> ```
>
> Schema:
>
> ```
> ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170127100855) do
>
>   create_table "model_a_model_bs", force: :cascade do |t|
>     t.integer  "model_a_id"
>     t.integer  "model_b_id"
>     t.datetime "created_at", null: false
>     t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
>     t.index ["model_a_id"], name: "index_model_a_model_bs_on_model_a_id"
>     t.index ["model_b_id"], name: "index_model_a_model_bs_on_model_b_id"
>   end
>
>   create_table "model_as", force: :cascade do |t|
>     t.string   "name"
>     t.datetime "created_at", null: false
>     t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
>   end
>
>   create_table "model_bs", force: :cascade do |t|
>     t.string   "interesting_thing"
>     t.datetime "created_at",        null: false
>     t.datetime "updated_at",        null: false
>   end
>
> end
> ```
>
> Gemfile:
>
> ```
> source 'https://rubygems.org'
>
> git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
>   repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
>   "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
> end
>
>
> # Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
> gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.1'
> # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
> gem 'sqlite3'
> # Use Puma as the app server
> gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
> # Use SCSS for stylesheets
> gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
> # Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
> gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
> # Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
> gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
> # See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
> # gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
>
> # Use jquery as the JavaScript library
> gem 'jquery-rails'
> # Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
> gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
> # Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
> gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
> # Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
> # gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
> # Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
> # gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
>
> # Use Capistrano for deployment
> # gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development
>
> group :development, :test do
>   # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
>   gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
> end
>
> group :development do
>   # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
>   gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
>   gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
>   # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
>   gem 'spring'
>   gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
> end
>
> # Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
> gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have dependent destroy on the join model too.

```
class ModelA < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :model_a_model_b, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :model_b, through: :model_a_model_b, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Or better yet, have foreign keys with `on_delete: :cascade` to get the database to delete them.

Comment: Just about to give this a try, thanks. 

Can you explain why that isn't needed with `has_many`? 

I think the `on_delete: :cascade` might be a better way of dealing with it in the long run.

Comment: Super! Next question may be how to achieve the equivalent of a before_remove callback... :)

Comment: Do you mean `has_and_belongs_to_many`?  I'd assume it'd be because there isn't a model so it removes the join, with a model you might want to have the model still available.

Comment: Nope. If I use `has_many :relationships` `has_many :things, through: :relationships, dependent: :destroy` then the destroy works OK. I don't need the extra statement

Comment: as for `before_remove`, I already knew that's not available on `has_one` but I've achieved what I need to for now by putting `dependent: :destroy` in the join model.

Comment: So that destroys relationships and things?  Not just things?

Comment: That example will destroy just the relationships, unless relationships has its own `dependent: :destroy` -- in most cases like this I'm using a `before_remove` callback that destroys the items on the other side of the join table, because this just seems tidier, and more explicit.